# Drupal ( NO SMTP Capability )

Tags: drupal, smtp, xampp

Ive setup drupal 7 in my work place where we dont have an internet access nor outgoing mail. We can mail ourselves internally only( Registered in the Exchage/Mail Domain).

I am using XAMPP to handle MySQL, Apache and Mercury but I cannot figure out how to send the confirmation mail of drupal, also the password resets to the valid mail of the user using my Internal Mail as the SMTP. Any help?

I can only also access the internet thru a proxy IP and Port that was given to me recently, so I was thinking of using free mail accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup your smtp server in `/xmpp/php/php.ini` ?

Comment: What must be the value of my smtp server in php.ini?  this is mine:
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

what value should I put in there?

Comment: If you have a smtp server on localhost, this is OK. If not, set your LAN smtp (mail) server IP there. If you dont have one, set your ISP SMTP adress there.